# When are objects deallocated when using ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Say I have a custom `NSObject` class called `customClass` with a property `NSMutableArray *thisArray;`

I instantiate `customClass *instance = [[customClass alloc] init]` in my root view controller. Somewhere in the the customClass implementation thisArray is set.

Now I have a property in my root view controller `NSMutableArray (strong,nonatomic) *anotherArray` and I set it via `anotherArray = customClass.thisArray`. If I then set customClass to nil, will `anotherArray` still point to an object in memory or is / should it be destroyed? What about the rest of the object and its properties memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `anotherArray = customClass.thisArray` in your root view controller, since `anotherArray` is a strong property the reference count is incremented so if `customClass` is `de-allocated` you will still have a array in memory with the property pointing to it.

Also, you probably find the example as above won't compile since you cannot do `anotherArray = customClass.thisArray`, you need to do either `[self setAnotherArray:[customClass thisArray]]` or use the backing variable, `_anotherArray = [customClass thisArray]`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use ARC, objects are deallocated when there are no more strong references to the object.

In your case `customClass` has a strong property `thisArray` and your view controller has a strong property `anotherArray`. When you assign an array to `customClass.thisArray` and there are no other strong references, `customClass` will keep `thisArray` in memory (because it has a strong reference to it). If you now assign `anotherArray = customClass.thisArray`, there are at least 2 strong references to the array.

If `customClass` get deallocated (which happens when there are no strong references to it) `anotherArray` still has a strong reference to the original array, so your array is still alive.

Comment: and how do retain objects themselves get deallocated? or is that there should never be any strong--strong relation ever anywhere, only strong-weak relation? meaning if we have a series of 5 objects in chain: `strong-weak-strong-weak-strong` we are good, but if its chained as: `strong-strong-strong-weak-weak` then it's problematic?